# Not able to post data to my web api - ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to post my form data to my API. While I am able to make a call, looks like no data is being posted.

What am I doing wrong? Also, I want to post the data in JSON format. Should I be doing JSON.stringify()?

P.S. Noob Here

```
<div id="response">
    <pre></pre>
</div>

<form id="my-form">
            <div id="app">
            <h1 style="color:#5bb7db;">Get Started</h1>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="src">Source:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="src" placeholder="source folder path">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="dest">Destination:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="dest" placeholder="destination folder path">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" id="sbmt" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    (function($){
        function processForm( e ){
        console.log( $(this).serialize() );
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost:3000/posts',
                dataType: 'text',
                type: 'post',
                cors: true,
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function( data, textStatus, jQxhr ){
                    $('#response pre').html( data );
                },
                error: function( jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown ){
                    console.log( errorThrown );
                }
            });

            e.preventDefault();
        }

        $('#my-form').submit( processForm );
    })(jQuery);
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set name for `source` and `destination` inputs

```
<input type="text" name="source" class="form-control" id="src" placeholder="source folder path">

<input type="text" name="destination" class="form-control" id="dest" placeholder="destination folder path">
```

Comment: Thank you. that works. How do I convert my form data into a JSON format?

Comment: I am trying to do a 
{ source: $('#source').val(), destination: $('#destination').val() }

but I am getting {source: undefined, destination: undefined}

Comment: To convert into a JSON you need to `serializeArray` like this `var data = JSON.stringify( $(this).serializeArray() );`

Comment: Awesome.I am getting the JSON. But not in the format I want. 
[{"name":"source","value":"fdaf"},{"name":"destination","value":"fdasfa "}]

I want something like
[{"source": "test", "destination": "test"}]

Comment: I don't think you can get this formula with `SerializeArray` function, I this you have to create your own array and `JSON.stringify` it.